# Can I make aws-serverless-java-container work with Swagger?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, serverless

I'm using [aws-serverless-java-container](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container) with Spring Boot and I'd like to have Swagger interactive documentation like [this one](http://petstore.swagger.io/).

I could serve it dynamically from AWS Lambda or generate the OpenAPI Specification during compilation and then just upload it to AWS S3.

Unfortunately, when I added to build.gradle:

```
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0')
```

and this configuration code to SwaggerConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.mypackage.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

I couldn't access my Swagger UI at this url: http://localhost:5000/swagger-ui.html. I got 404 Not Found.

However, I was able to access OpenAPI Specification at this url: http://localhost:5000/v2/api-docs. Although this url (`/v2/api-docs`) wasn't working (404 Not found) when I uploaded my app to AWS Lambda.

So, how to make it work on AWS Lambda or how to generate it during compilation for S3 uploading?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is likely too late for you. However, I suspect this has something to do with how the Events for the function are configured in your SAM template. In order to accept requests to the root of API, you need to add an additional ANY method mapping:

```
Events:
  RootResource:
    Type: Api
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Method: ANY
  OtherResources:
    Type: Api
    Properties:
      Path: /{proxy+}
      Method: ANY
```